# interrupt based LEDs up counter on an atmega32

Tags: c, avr, isr, atmega32

l am designing an interrupt based number counter which shows the values as they increment on 8 LEDs using an atmega32. My problem is my ISR(interrupt service routine)is not able to light up the LEDs as l increment from INT0below is the code l made, only the ISR is not lighting the LEDs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LahFd.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

In `SR`, the `count` variable is on the stack. Its value does *not* persist across invocations.

---

Here is your original code [with annotations]:

```
SR(INT0_vect)
{
    DDRA = 0xFF;
// NOTE/BUG: this is on the stack and is reinitialized to zero on each
// invocation
    unsigned char count = 0;

// NOTE/BUG: this will _always_ output zero
    PORTA = count;
// NOTE/BUG: this has no effect because count does _not_ persist upon return
    count++;

    return;
}
```

---

You need to add `static` to get the value to persist:

```
void
SR(INT0_vect)
{
    DDRA = 0xFF;
    static unsigned char count = 0;

    PORTA = count;
    count++;
}
```